# matlplotlib with opencv gives a different image with the same pixel values

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I've been trying to modify the pixels of an image slightly, but the colors are getting distorted. So, I  multiplied every pixel with 1 and saw the result.[image]

Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2

mud1 = cv2.imread('mud.jpeg')
print mud1.shape

mask = np.random.random_integers(1,1,size=(81,81,3))

print mask.shape
print mask[21][21][2]
print mud1[21][21][2]
mud1new = np.multiply(mud1,mask)
print mud1new[21][21][2]

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(mud1),plt.title('Original')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(mud1new),plt.title('Masked')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.savefig('problem.jpeg')
plt.show()
```

The pixels remain unchanged but somehow the image I see is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `np.random.random_integers` returns objects that are `int64` whereas your loaded image is `uint8` so when you multiply the two together, `mud1new` becomes an `int64` array. When using [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow), it expects the following types

> - MxN – values to be mapped (float or int)
> - MxNx3 – RGB (float or uint8)
> - MxNx4 – RGBA (float or uint8)

To fix this, you should cast `mud1new` as a `uint8` prior to display with `imshow`

```
mud1new = mud1new.astype(np.unit8)
plt.imshow(mud1new)
```

You could also convert `mud1new` to a `float` but that would require that all of your values should be between 0 and 1 so you'd have to divide everything by 255.

> The value for each component of MxNx3 and MxNx4 float arrays should be in the range 0.0 to 1.0.

```
mud1new_float = mud1new.astype(np.float) / 255.0;
plt.imshow(mud1new_float)
```